# Hibernate Not In Collection Table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class `ReleaseNote` saved in the table `RELEASE_NOTES` and a table `RELEASE_NOTE_USER_READ` with the columns `RELEASE_NOTE_ID` and `USER_ID` where I want to save which users have already read a releaseNote, so I don't show it again.

Since we are using a microservice architekture I don't have a user object in that microservice and don't want to add one. Although it won't be a problem to add a field usersRead to the ReleaseNote which contains the userId of all the users who have read the releaseNote.

I need to perform two actions:

1. Pass a list of releaseNoteIds to be saved in the table for a given userId, so I can keep track of the releaseNotes a user has read.
2. Select all releaseNotes a user has not read. The SQL-Statement for this would look like:
   `SELECT * FROM RELEASE_NOTES WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT RELEASE_NOTE_ID FROM RELEASE_NOTE_USER_READ WHERE USER_ID = :userId)`

How can I achieve this using the `EntityManager` or Hibernate specific functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself. Add field Set usersRead to ReleaseNote and annotate like the following:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "RELEASE_NOTES_USER_READ",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "RELEASE_NOTE_ID"))
@Column(name = "USER_ID", table = "RELEASE_NOTES_USER_READ")
private Set<Integer> usersRead = new HashSet<>();
```